# How to add a website link to HTML website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to add images to html website but theres one thing i am not sure how to do, even after searching plenty of sites on the internet.

I created a small animation using java script on some other IDE, and I copied the link of my output:

https://g2mjl.csb.app/

I want to paste this link onto my html website but I do not know how to. If i use the regular `<img src ....` it does not work.

Basically the animation was coded in `Java Script` and the code for js is as follows:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import TypeIt from "typeit";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");

new TypeIt("#inner-demo-2", {
  speed: 100,
  lifelike: true,
  cursor: true,
  cursorSpeed: 200,
  loop: true
})
  .pause(1000)
  .type('<span style="font-family: Segoe UI Emoji"></span>', {
    html: true
  })
  .type("&nbspHi&nbspthere!&nbspI'm&nbspHussain Omer")
  
  .go();
```

**How can I add this code into my html file?**

Also, this is for my personal website and not for school or anything, so answers are much appreciated!

I am fairly new to html too, as I started learning it a week ago, so help is really appreciated!

I want the animation to display at the very top and the width of it should cover basically my whole page but should be at the very top

Heres my html website code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Portfolio site template</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Repl.it_logo.svg/220px-Repl.it_logo.png">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      
        <div class="container">
      
        <!--────────────────Header───────────────-->
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="#home">
              <img src="https://newsletter-images--timmy-i-chen.repl.co/logo-light.png" alt="repl logo" />
        </a>
        <nav>   
         <ul class="nav-bar"><div class="bg"></div>
            <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
            
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!--─────────────────Home────────────────-->
      <div id="home">
         <div class="filter"></div>
         <section class="intro">
          <p>Short Description.</p>
          <p>Something more about yourself.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              
          <!--────social media links─────-->
             
          <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-codepen'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-github'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-linkedin-in'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
             
         </section> 
      </div>  
        
      <!--───────────────Projects───────────────-->
      <div id="projects"> 
         <h3>My Projects.<hr></h3>
          <p>Here are some of my projects, you may like.</p>
          <div class="work-box">
          <div class="work">
        <!--───────────────card───────────────-->
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518611507436-f9221403cca2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462642109801-4ac2971a3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1266&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485815457792-d1a966f9bde0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517842645767-c639042777db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div> 
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535556116002-6281ff3e9f36?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=781&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483546416237-76fd26bbcdd1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <a href="" target="_blank"> <!--Link to project-->
                <div class="work-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div></a>
            </div>    
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
         
        <!--──────────────Contact────────────────-->
      <div id="contact">
          <!--────social media links─────-->
           <h3>Contact.<hr></h3>
           <p>Feel free to contact me on my social media.</p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-codepen'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-github'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class='fab fa-linkedin-in'></i></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>

    </main>
      <footer class="copyright">© 2020 
          <a href="https://repl.it/@lilykhan" target="_blank"> Lilykhan.</a>
          <!-- be sure to give credit to me :) -->
     </footer>
      
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CLASS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

:root{
    --main-background: #0b0c0f;
    --main-fonts-color: #fff;
    --main-decor-color:#00a9e2;
    --main-header-background:#21252e;
    --main-font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--main-background);
}

/*────────────────── 
       header
──────────────────*/

header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-around; 
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 5;
}
.nav-show{
    opacity: 0;
}

header:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    background: var(--main-header-background);
}

.logo img{
    padding-top: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar{
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
}

a.nav-link{
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.active{
    background: var(--main-decor-color);
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background: var(--main-decor-color);
}

/*──────────────────
       home
──────────────────*/

#home{  
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#home .filter{
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544099858-75feeb57f01b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity:.20;
}  

.intro {
    text-align:center;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.intro  p{
    margin: 5px;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
    text-align:center;
}

 h3{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px var(--main-decor-color);
}


/*──────────────────
    social media
──────────────────*/

.social-media{
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    position: center;
    align-items: space-around;
    justify-content:center;
}

.social-media a {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
}

.social-media a i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.social-media  a:hover {
    color: var(--main-decor-color);
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px var(--main-decor-color);
}

/*──────────────────
      projects
──────────────────*/

#projects{
    margin-top:100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:center;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
}
#projects h3{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
#projects p{
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
    font-size:1.2rem;
    padding: 10px;
}

.work{
    display: flex; 
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:12px;
    background:var(--main-decor-color);
}

.card img{
    width: 100%;
    height:70%;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.card .work-content{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card .work-content:hover{
    color:#202020;
}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem gray;
}

/*──────────────────
      Contact
──────────────────*/

#contact{
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--main-fonts-color);
}
    
#contact p{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
}

/*────────────────── 
       footer
──────────────────*/

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--main-header-background);
}

.copyright {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.copyright a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: var(--main-font-family);
}

.copyright a:hover{
    color: var(--main-decor-color);
}

/*──── hr ─────*/

hr {
    background: var(--main-decor-color);
    margin: 2px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: hidden;
    margin-inline-start: auto;
    margin-inline-end: auto;
}

/*────────────────── 
     Scrollbar
──────────────────*/
::-webkit-Scrollbar{
    width: 5px; 
    background: rgba(5,5,5,1);
}
::-webkit-Scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: var(--main-decor-color);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px var(--main-decor-color);
}
::-webkit-Scrollbar-track{
    margin-top: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/*────────────────── 
     hamburger
──────────────────*/
.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger div{
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    margin: 5px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}

.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        transform: translatex(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform:translatex(0px);
    }
}

/*────────────────── 
    media queries
──────────────────*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1484px) and (min-width: 1214px) {
    .work{
        padding:20px 20%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1214px) and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .work{
        padding:20px 12%;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    #home, #projects, #contact{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    header{
        background-color: var(--main-header-background);
    }
    .logo{
        position:absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 30px;
    }
    .nav-show{
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    .nav-bar{
        position:fixed;
        top: 0px;
        right:0;
        width:60%;
        height: 100vh;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:space-evenly;
        background:var(--main-header-background);
        transform:translatex(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .hamburger{
        position:absolute;
        top: 17px;
        right: 25%;
        display: block;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 5;
    }   
    .nav-bar li{
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform:translatex(0%);
}
```

JS CLASS:

```
// header scrolling effect
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
      $('header').addClass('nav-show');
          
    } 
    else{
        $('header').removeClass('nav-show');
    }
       
})

//hamburger
const navSlide = () => {
     const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
     const navbar = document.querySelector(".nav-bar");
     const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-bar li");

     hamburger.onclick = () => {
        
     navbar.classList.toggle("nav-active");
         
      //Animation links
     navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = "";
        } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7+1}s`;
           }
        });
      //hamburger animation
     hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");
    }
     
    }

window.onload = () => navSlide();
```

BTW this is a free html website template i got

Comment: That's not a GIF.  If I inspect the source at that link it's a full blown website.

Comment: Do you know a way i can add that to my website?

Comment: First off, don't call it a GIF.  You are misleading people right off the bat with what we are dealing with.  Secondly, the first thought I would have towards embedding another website in your website would be with an iframe.

Comment: Can you show me? I will also change my title right now

Comment: This is a Vue app, so either learn enough about Vue to know how to integrate that into your own website, or alternatively if you just want it "like an image": screenshoot the animation _as a GIF_ or even as a movie, and then put that on your site with `<img>` or `<video`>.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe  <iframe> documentation

Comment: @Taplar, I tried that but i am getting a blank output

Comment: If you look at the sandbox (click on the button bottom right of [link]https://g2mjl.csb.app/) you will see the Javascript that goes to make up this animation. You could put that in with your own code possibly, or use https://g2mjl.csb.app/ as the src for an iframe (but then you are reliant on that site existing in the future).

Comment: like the box part shows up, but theres nothing inside the box or the frame if u wanna say

Comment: @ A Haworth, how will i put the code inside there tho? like the code goes for java script, and what do i put inside html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using an iframe would be your best bet if you want to display the actual app on your website.

This is how you would implement the iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://g2mjl.csb.app/" title="My App"></iframe>
```

That being said, iframes are tricky. Depending on the website, it's possible that an iframe blocking policy is in place which could prevent you from embedding your app.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Now, if all you want is a gif, I've gone ahead and done that for you, although, you may want to upload your own with something like [giphy](https://support.giphy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019674452-How-To-Make-A-GIF).

Here is a link to a gif I've created from your app: https://media.giphy.com/media/U9vs87YlzO1KrlFSaG/giphy.gif

You can also see it by running the snippet below:

```html
<a href="https://g2mjl.csb.app/"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/boq1oJ25cQ21rpLRmo/giphy.gif" /></a>
```

I wrapped the image with an anchor that will lead to your app page but you can just implement it in your `img` `src` as you originally attempted like this:

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/boq1oJ25cQ21rpLRmo/giphy.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
<h2>Iframe - Target for a Link</h2>

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<p>When the target attribute of a link matches the name of an iframe, the link will open in the iframe.</p>
```